# Chef use of MySQL installation as a recipe

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am looking at Chef-repo and I have a nice setup so far where I have a HA Proxy as a load blanancer connected to two wordpress servers, What I am looking to do is setup a database with a data bag in the following format passwords, passwords is abc123.

I have this data bag encrypted with a key and everything looks hunky dorey!

Now I have the latest mysql cookbook from the supermarket but I am unable to find a place to set the password during the recipe setup.

I was looking at:

> Then, in a recipe:

```
mysql_service 'default' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.5'
  initial_root_password 'change me'
  action [:create, :start]
end

mysql_config 'default' do
  source 'mysite.cnf.erb'
  notifies :restart, 'mysql_service[default]'
  action :create
end
```

> Source: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql

But I am very unsure were this recipe is meant to go.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: The cookbooks available from supermarket are increasingly designed to be used as libraries. Add mysql as a dependency and use it's resources above in a "db" recipe associated with your "application cookbook".  For more information on cookbook patterns, I recommend: http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/

Comment: Would you have any knowledge on how I would call a variable from a databag that is encrypted into a recipe?

Comment: Example using encrypted data bags http://www.justnudge.com/2014/08/31/Encrypting-data-with-chef.html and a second example using the alternative Chef vault mechanism http://engineering.ooyala.com/blog/keeping-secrets-chef

Comment: Thank you! :D I will check them out!